# Add dynamic data in XML body for AXIOS Post

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-router, axios

I need to post a request using AXIOS. The request body is in XML format. I am able to POST a request using static data in XML body using AXIOS but wanted to pass the value dynamically.

Can you please let me know how can i add dynamic value(TripName,TotalFare etc.) in xml body?

```
requestBody='<Itinerary xmlns="http://www.testsol.com/api/travel/trip/2010/06">\
    <TripName>SFO Trip- air and hotel </TripName>\
    <Comments />\
    <StartDateLocal>2020-05-10T07:25:00</StartDateLocal>\
    <EndDateLocal>2020-05-14T23:59:00</EndDateLocal>\
    <Bookings>\          
        <Booking>\
               <AirlineTickets>\
                <AirlineTicket>\
                    <DateCreatedUtc>2020-05-11T07:34:13</DateCreatedUtc>\
                    <DateModifiedUtc>2020-05-13T10:52:27</DateModifiedUtc>\
                    <IssueDateTime>2020-05-11T00:34:13</IssueDateTime>\
                    <TotalFare>3948.0000</TotalFare>\
                    <TotalFareCurrency>INR</TotalFareCurrency>\
                    <AirlineTicketCoupons>\
                        <AirlineTicketCoupon>\                            
                            <EndCityCode>DEL</EndCityCode>\
                            <FlightNumber>198</FlightNumber>\
                            <StartCityCode>BLR</StartCityCode>\
                            <StartDateLocal>2020-03-19T20:30:00</StartDateLocal>\
                            <Vendor>SG</Vendor>\
                        </AirlineTicketCoupon>\
                    </AirlineTicketCoupons>\
                </AirlineTicket>\
            </AirlineTickets>\               
            </Passengers>\            
            <PassengerCount>1</PassengerCount>\
        </Booking>\
    </Bookings>\
</Itinerary>';

 const config_req = {
      headers: {
        //  Accept: "application/json",
        Authorization: "Bearer " + token,
      },
    };
```

**CODE SNIPPET**

```
 axios
      .post("https://test.com/api/travel/trip", requestBody, config_req)
      .then((result) => {
        console.log("create Itin API" + result.data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
        console.log(error.data);
      });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) for your request body.

For example

```
const startDateLocal = ...
const endDateTotal = ...
const dateCreated = ...
...
requestBody=`<Itinerary xmlns="http://www.testsol.com/api/travel/trip/2010/06">\
    <StartDateLocal>${startDateLocal}</StartDateLocal>\
    <EndDateLocal>${endDateTotal}</EndDateLocal>\
    <Bookings>\          
        <Booking>\
               <AirlineTickets>\
                <AirlineTicket>\
                    <DateCreatedUtc>${dateCreated}</DateCreatedUtc>\
                    <DateModifiedUtc>${dateModified}</DateModifiedUtc>\
                    <IssueDateTime>${issueDate}</IssueDateTime>\
                    <TotalFare>${totalFare}</TotalFare>\
                    <TotalFareCurrency>${currency}</TotalFareCurrency>\
                </AirlineTicket>\
            </AirlineTickets>\               
            </Passengers>\            
            <PassengerCount>${passengerCount}</PassengerCount>\
        </Booking>\
    </Bookings>\
</Itinerary>`;
```

Assuming you have all the variables defined

Comment: @gzcz- The example you share works for single tag. I need to update multiple values in xml. May i know how can i do it?

Comment: You can make the whole request body a template string... `const body = <Ticket><TotalFare>${totalFare}</TotalFare><IssueDateTime>${date}</IssueDateTime></Ticket>`. Updated the answer to show you a better example.