# Axios returning binary data instead of XML

Tags: node.js, axios

Been spending the past few hours figuring out why Axios is doing this.

I tried to do this in the request library in nodeJS and it works fine, but Axios isn't.

Essentially what i'm doing is sending a request of XML data:

```
 var options = {
        'method': 'POST',
        'url': 'https://rvices.svc',
        'headers': {
          'Content-Type': 'text/xml; charset=utf-8',
          'SOAPAction': 'http://etProject'
        },
        data: xmlData};
```

with XMLData looking simliar to :

```
 let xmlData = `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:com="http://p" xmlns:pws="http://"
```

etc etc (it has mostly private data in it so I stripped most of it out).

when I try to use axios to get this

```
const testData = await axios(options)
```

i get returned a whole lot of code that looks like this:

```
    '���_\x1B�\f�10�\x17�Ч�{O�\x00��5h�S�������\x0F���s�(+Ғ�\x0F�����m�\x15\x01\x13��6b��\x06%\x00��\x15p8<;��W�4����\x0B���\x01���e�\x7FvZ�{���Ï������\x06��-�z��\x01}�!�r�A�\x13��\x11O�w6ũ���{�\x03����;{����\x01\x7Fy��KoՎ���\x1Bߚe��W��mЇ�qD�a��[�7Ӄ���@��F<\x1C/mF�{\x03�h��#�\x16�\x11\x1F\x1F�L9\x0FM\x8A\x0E�\x
17�h���\x03�4�7�f=bj*8�p�\x13_�\x17�5���_�Ӑ�|M>����\r��F�8q�iE�#��\x0E?�v�������O�xq3���x�Q�튱\x1F?G&HG9��6���V\x1B⫯Ev\x01rc\x13\x10�\'�7��`�Ii��x�~LM6�#˒74#@�����f�*\x7F\x16(5|\x1CWl��\x07\t\x1F��z�\x15\x00\x1B��4�\x13���LCTG�\x1FI�����\fec�h\x02�~��i`�:Ғ�\x0F���y\b#�]V��g��Ӈ�\x14|���6~\x19~c`�/�O���M\x01��k\x
10�\'+���\x07S\r?|��T�A�\x0FӒ�\x0F��ܷ\'.s�!>�tbX\x05�\fs\x18�\r�"`���\x10lV٠\x05@ܲ�\x02\x0E\x07h���\n' +
    '���[�7}�>54 r�����ʦ\x15�\x17��\x0E:
```

that is the right amount of characters (100k +) but jumbled

compared to doing this with request which returns the xml back I expect ala:

```
</b:ProjectTaskTypeDetail></b:PwsProjectTaskTypeElement><b:PwsProjectTaskTypeElement><b:ProjectTaskTypeDetail><b:ExternalSystemIdentifier i:nil="true"/><b:ProjectTaskTypeId i:nil="true"/><b:ProjectTaskTypeUid>5776</b:ProjectTaskTypeUid><b:ProjectTaskTypeName>Faon</b:Proj
ectTaskTypeName>
```

one thing I noticed is axios is breaking my request up into multiple lines like this:

```
 '<com:PwsProjectRef><com:ProjectCode>201268</com:ProjectCode></com:PwsProjectRef>\n' +
      '\n' +
      '<com:PwsProjectRef><com:ProjectCode>210115-01</com:ProjectCode></com:PwsProjectRef>\n' +
      '\n' +
```

even though there's no \n's in my request or breaks like that.

So i'm wondering if anyone has ran into this before and knows how to solve it?

Request is working but request (from what I can tell?) doesn't work with  asynch code (i'm probably wrong about this)

Sorry for the vagueness!

Comment: So i've deduced that with Axios it has to do with my request, which is being generated like this:

```
idArray.forEach(e=>{
        genXML = genXML + e.XMLCode;
        return genXML;
      })

let generatedxmlData = xmlData + genXML;
  xmlData = generatedxmlData + `</sch:ProjectIdentities></pws:serviceRequest></pws:PwsGetProject></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>`;

```

Answer (score 3):

### In v1.2.1, it is fixed this error.

try with this code

Save as get-data.js file

```
const axios = require("axios");

const getData = async () => {
    try {
        const resp = await axios.get('your xml URL',
            {
                headers: {
                    'Accept-Encoding': 'application/xml',
                }
            }
        );
        console.log(resp.data);
    } catch (err) {
        // Handle Error Here
        console.error(err);
    }
};

getData()
```

```
npm install axios
node get-data.js
```

Comment: This got me closer I think! 

Seems like the issue is whenever axios sees \n in my XML request it breaks it into a new line, which breaks the XML formatting

Comment: @sylargaf, It seems server's issue, may be post processing after got response. Any way to reproduce from me? If not It hard to handle without reproduce in my hand.

Comment: I'll try to get something reproducible and thank you for the help. I actually find something similiar on here that someone had the same issue with....but of course never posted their solution

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62324140/add-dynamic-data-in-xml-body-for-axios-post

i'm trying to do the same thing - dynamically insert blocks of code into the request, which is where this seems to break. if I mash it all together it isn't accepted :(

Answer (score 2):

The response is being returned in a compressed binary format, but
Axios does not understand the compression format that is being returned from the server. Try forcing the response to a specific compression algorithm like 'deflate' which axios understands. 'gzip' may also work.

The axios 'decompress' option tells axios to automatically decompress the binary data.

```js
var options = {
  'method': 'POST',
  'url': 'https://rvices.svc',
  'headers': {
    'Accept-Encoding': 'deflate'
    'Content-Type': 'text/xml; charset=utf-8',
    'SOAPAction': 'http://etProject'
  },
  data: xmlData,
  decompress: true    
};

<!-- end snippet -->
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be using the `responseType` config option to set the expected response which reflects the [`Accept` HTTP header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept) and not the `Content-Type` one:

```
 const options = {
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'https://rvices.svc',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'text/xml; charset=utf-8',
      'SOAPAction': 'http://etProject'
    },
    data: xmlData,
    responseType: 'document',
    responseEncoding: 'utf8'
};

const testData = await axios(options);
```

Comment: Just tried this - same thing :( 

It's weird because I can run other similiar requests in Axios but just this one seems to do this