# Format Dynamic Generated XML for Axios

Tags: javascript, node.js, xml, axios

[Axios returning binary data instead of XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74632776/axios-returning-binary-data-instead-of-xml/74633065?noredirect=1#comment131736253_74633065)

Hey all, I asked this question earlier and got further with my research into what its doing. *however* I am having a issue with Axios in particular in sending out a dynamicly generated XML response.

The XML request I am generating is essentially this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
                      <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:com="http://projectorpsa.com/DataContracts/Shared/Common/"
                      xmlns:pws="http://projectorpsa.com/PwsProjectorServices/" xmlns:req="http://projectorpsa.com/DataContracts/Requests/" xmlns:sch="http://projectorpsa.com/DataContracts/Shared/Scheduling/">
                         <soapenv:Header />
                         <soapenv:Body>
                            <pws:PwsGetProject>
                               <pws:serviceRequest>
                                  <req:SessionTicket>BZZ=</req:SessionTicket>
                                  <sch:Mode>R</sch:Mode>
                                  <sch:ProjectIdentities>
                                      <com:PwsProjectRef><com:ProjectCode>201268</com:ProjectCode></com:PwsProjectRef>
                                      <com:PwsProjectRef><com:ProjectCode>201268</com:ProjectCode></com:PwsProjectRef>
                                      <com:PwsProjectRef><com:ProjectCode>210115-01</com:ProjectCode></com:PwsProjectRef>
                                      <com:PwsProjectRef><com:ProjectCode>210115-02</com:ProjectCode></com:PwsProjectRef>
                                      <com:PwsProjectRef><com:ProjectCode>210115-03</com:ProjectCode></com:PwsProjectRef>
                                      <com:PwsProjectRef><com:ProjectCode>210115-04</com:ProjectCode></com:PwsProjectRef>
                                      <com:PwsProjectRef><com:ProjectCode>210115-05</com:ProjectCode></com:PwsProjectRef>
                                      <com:PwsProjectRef><com:ProjectCode>210115-06</com:ProjectCode></com:PwsProjectRef>
                                      <com:PwsProjectRef><com:ProjectCode>210115-07</com:ProjectCode></com:PwsProjectRef>
                                      <com:PwsProjectRef><com:ProjectCode>2103101-01</com:ProjectCode></com:PwsProjectRef>
                                      <com:PwsProjectRef><com:ProjectCode>2103101-02</com:ProjectCode></com:PwsProjectRef>
                                      <com:PwsProjectRef><com:ProjectCode>2103101-03</com:ProjectCode></com:PwsProjectRef>
                                      <com:PwsProjectRef><com:ProjectCode>2103101-04</com:ProjectCode></com:PwsProjectRef>
                                      <com:PwsProjectRef><com:ProjectCode>2103101-05</com:ProjectCode></com:PwsProjectRef>
                                      <com:PwsProjectRef><com:ProjectCode>2103101-06</com:ProjectCode></com:PwsProjectRef>
                                      <com:PwsProjectRef><com:ProjectCode>2103101-07</com:ProjectCode></com:PwsProjectRef>
                                      <com:PwsProjectRef><com:ProjectCode>2103101-08</com:ProjectCode></com:PwsProjectRef>
                                      <com:PwsProjectRef><com:ProjectCode>2103101-09</com:ProjectCode></com:PwsProjectRef>
                                      <com:PwsProjectRef><com:ProjectCode>2103101-10</com:ProjectCode></com:PwsProjectRef>
                                      <com:PwsProjectRef><com:ProjectCode>2103103</com:ProjectCode></com:PwsProjectRef>
                                      <com:PwsProjectRef><com:ProjectCode>2103110-01</com:ProjectCode></com:PwsProjectRef>
                                      <com:PwsProjectRef><com:ProjectCode>2103110-02</com:ProjectCode></com:PwsProjectRef>
                                      <com:PwsProjectRef><com:ProjectCode>2103110-03</com:ProjectCode></com:PwsProjectRef>
                                      <com:PwsProjectRef><com:ProjectCode>210378-01</com:ProjectCode></com:PwsProjectRef>
                                      <com:PwsProjectRef><com:ProjectCode>210378-02</com:ProjectCode></com:PwsProjectRef>
                                      <com:PwsProjectRef><com:ProjectCode>210378-03</com:ProjectCode></com:PwsProjectRef>
                                      <com:PwsProjectRef><com:ProjectCode>210378-04</com:ProjectCode></com:PwsProjectRef>
                                      <com:PwsProjectRef><com:ProjectCode>210378-05</com:ProjectCode></com:PwsProjectRef>
                                      <com:PwsProjectRef><com:ProjectCode>210378-06</com:ProjectCode></com:PwsProjectRef>
                                      <com:PwsProjectRef><com:ProjectCode>210378-07</com:ProjectCode></com:PwsProjectRef>
                                      <com:PwsProjectRef><com:ProjectCode>210378-08</com:ProjectCode></com:PwsProjectRef>
                                      <com:PwsProjectRef><com:ProjectCode>210378-09</com:ProjectCode></com:PwsProjectRef>
                                      <com:PwsProjectRef><com:ProjectCode>210378-10</com:ProjectCode></com:PwsProjectRef>
                                      <com:PwsProjectRef><com:ProjectCode>210966</com:ProjectCode></com:PwsProjectRef>
                                      <com:PwsProjectRef><com:ProjectCode>211245-01</com:ProjectCode></com:PwsProjectRef>
                                      <com:PwsProjectRef><com:ProjectCode>211245-02</com:ProjectCode></com:PwsProjectRef>
                                      <com:PwsProjectRef><com:ProjectCode>211245-03</com:ProjectCode></com:PwsProjectRef>
                                      <com:PwsProjectRef><com:ProjectCode>211245-04</com:ProjectCode></com:PwsProjectRef>
                                      <com:PwsProjectRef><com:ProjectCode>211245-05</com:ProjectCode></com:PwsProjectRef>
                                      <com:PwsProjectRef><com:ProjectCode>211245-06</com:ProjectCode></com:PwsProjectRef>
                                      <com:PwsProjectRef><com:ProjectCode>211245-07</com:ProjectCode></com:PwsProjectRef>
                                      <com:PwsProjectRef><com:ProjectCode>2201146</com:ProjectCode></com:PwsProjectRef>
                                      <com:PwsProjectRef><com:ProjectCode>ARCH - 3708608015</com:ProjectCode></com:PwsProjectRef>
                                  </sch:ProjectIdentities>
                               </pws:serviceRequest>
                            </pws:PwsGetProject>
                         </soapenv:Body>
                      </soapenv:Envelope>
```

which I generate through a for Loop:

```
//xmlCode Example: XMLCode: `<com:PwsProjectRef><com:ProjectCode>${e.ProjectCode[0]}</com:ProjectCode></com:PwsProjectRef>` 

  for(let i = 0; i < idArray.length; i++){

        if (i === 0){
          genXML = idArray[i].XMLCode + "\n";
        }
        if (i === idArray.length - 1){
          genXML = genXML + "                                      " + idArray[i].XMLCode;
        }
        else{
          genXML = genXML + "                                      " + idArray[i].XMLCode + "\n"
        }
      }
```

which Axios is generating as:

```
 data: '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n' +
      '                      <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:com="http://projectorpsa.com/DataContracts/Shared/Common/" \n' +
      '                      xmlns:pws="http://projectorpsa.com/PwsProjectorServices/" xmlns:req="http://projectorpsa.com/DataContracts/Requests/" xmlns:sch="http://projectorpsa.com/DataContracts/Shared/Scheduling/">\n' +
      '                         <soapenv:Header />\n' +
      '                         <soapenv:Body>\n' +
      '                            <pws:PwsGetProject>\n' +
      '                               <pws:serviceRequest>\n' +
      '                                  <req:SessionTicket>BZ</req:SessionTicket>\n' +
      '                                  <sch:Mode>R</sch:Mode>\n' +
      '                                  <sch:ProjectIdentities>\n' +
      '                                      <com:PwsProjectRef><com:ProjectCode>201268</com:ProjectCode></com:PwsProjectRef>\n' +
      '                                      <com:PwsProjectRef><com:ProjectCode>201268</com:ProjectCode></com:PwsProjectRef>\n' +
      '                                      <com:PwsProjectRef><com:ProjectCode>210115-01</com:ProjectCode></com:PwsProjectRef>\n' +
      '                                      <com:PwsProjectRef><com:ProjectCode>210115-02</com:ProjectCode></com:PwsProjectRef>\n' +
      '                                      <com:PwsProjectRef><com:ProjectCode>210115-03</com:ProjectCode></com:PwsProjectRef>\n' +
      '                                      <com:PwsProjectRef><com:ProjectCode>210115-04</com:ProjectCode></com:PwsProjectRef>\n' +
      '                                      <com:PwsProjectRef><com:ProjectCode>210115-05</com:ProjectCode></com:PwsProjectRef>\n' +
      '                                      <com:PwsProjectRef><com:ProjectCode>210115-06</com:ProjectCode></com:PwsProjectRef>\n' +
      '                                      <com:PwsProjectRef><com:ProjectCode>210115-07</com:ProjectCode></com:PwsProjectRef>\n' +
      '                                      <com:PwsProjectRef><com:ProjectCode>2103101-01</com:ProjectCode></com:PwsProjectRef>\n' +
      '                                      <com:PwsProjectRef><com:ProjectCode>2103101-02</com:ProjectCode></com:PwsProjectRef>\n' +
      '                                      <com:PwsProjectRef><com:ProjectCode>2103101-03</com:ProjectCode></com:PwsProjectRef>\n' +
      '                                      <com:PwsProjectRef><com:ProjectCode>2103101-04</com:ProjectCode></com:PwsProjectRef>\n' +
      '                                      <com:PwsProjectRef><com:ProjectCode>2103101-05</com:ProjectCode></com:PwsProjectRef>\n' +
      '                                      <com:PwsProjectRef><com:ProjectCode>2103101-06</com:ProjectCode></com:PwsProjectRef>\n' +
      '                                      <com:PwsProjectRef><com:ProjectCode>2103101-07</com:ProjectCode></com:PwsProjectRef>\n' +
      '                                      <com:PwsProjectRef><com:ProjectCode>2103101-08</com:ProjectCode></com:PwsProjectRef>\n' +
      '                                      <com:PwsProjectRef><com:ProjectCode>2103101-09</com:ProjectCode></com:PwsProjectRef>\n' +
      '                                      <com:PwsProjectRef><com:ProjectCode>2103101-10</com:ProjectCode></com:PwsProjectRef>\n' +
      '                                      <com:PwsProjectRef><com:ProjectCode>2103103</com:ProjectCode></com:PwsProjectRef>\n' +
      '                                      <com:PwsProjectRef><com:ProjectCode>2103110-01</com:ProjectCode></com:PwsProjectRef>\n' +
      '                                      <com:PwsProjectRef><com:ProjectCode>2103110-02</com:ProjectCode></com:PwsProjectRef>\n' +
      '                                      <com:PwsProjectRef><com:ProjectCode>2103110-03</com:ProjectCode></com:PwsProjectRef>\n' +
      '                                      <com:PwsProjectRef><com:ProjectCode>210378-01</com:ProjectCode></com:PwsProjectRef>\n' +
      '                                      <com:PwsProjectRef><com:ProjectCode>210378-02</com:ProjectCode></com:PwsProjectRef>\n' +
      '                                      <com:PwsProjectRef><com:ProjectCode>210378-03</com:ProjectCode></com:PwsProjectRef>\n' +
      '                                      <com:PwsProjectRef><com:ProjectCode>210378-04</com:ProjectCode></com:PwsProjectRef>\n' +
      '                                      <com:PwsProjectRef><com:ProjectCode>210378-05</com:ProjectCode></com:PwsProjectRef>\n' +
      '                                      <com:PwsProjectRef><com:ProjectCode>210378-06</com:ProjectCode></com:PwsProjectRef>\n' +
      '                                      <com:PwsProjectRef><com:ProjectCode>210378-07</com:ProjectCode></com:PwsProjectRef>\n' +
      '                                      <com:PwsProjectRef><com:ProjectCode>210378-08</com:ProjectCode></com:PwsProjectRef>\n' +
      '                                      <com:PwsProjectRef><com:ProjectCode>210378-09</com:ProjectCode></com:PwsProjectRef>\n' +
      '                                      <com:PwsProjectRef><com:ProjectCode>210378-10</com:ProjectCode></com:PwsProjectRef>\n' +
      '                                      <com:PwsProjectRef><com:ProjectCode>210966</com:ProjectCode></com:PwsProjectRef>\n' +
      '                                      <com:PwsProjectRef><com:ProjectCode>211245-01</com:ProjectCode></com:PwsProjectRef>\n' +
      '                                      <com:PwsProjectRef><com:ProjectCode>211245-02</com:ProjectCode></com:PwsProjectRef>\n' +
      '                                      <com:PwsProjectRef><com:ProjectCode>211245-03</com:ProjectCode></com:PwsProjectRef>\n' +
      '                                      <com:PwsProjectRef><com:ProjectCode>211245-04</com:ProjectCode></com:PwsProjectRef>\n' +
      '                                      <com:PwsProjectRef><com:ProjectCode>211245-05</com:ProjectCode></com:PwsProjectRef>\n' +
      '                                      <com:PwsProjectRef><com:ProjectCode>211245-06</com:ProjectCode></com:PwsProjectRef>\n' +
      '                                      <com:PwsProjectRef><com:ProjectCode>211245-07</com:ProjectCode></com:PwsProjectRef>\n' +
      '                                      <com:PwsProjectRef><com:ProjectCode>2201146</com:ProjectCode></com:PwsProjectRef>\n' +
      '                                      <com:PwsProjectRef><com:ProjectCode>2201147</com:ProjectCode></com:PwsProjectRef>\n' +
      '                                      <com:PwsProjectRef><com:ProjectCode>220340-01</com:ProjectCode></com:PwsProjectRef>\n' +
      '                                      <com:PwsProjectRef><com:ProjectCode>2205110</com:ProjectCode></com:PwsProjectRef>\n' +
      '                                      <com:PwsProjectRef><com:ProjectCode>220967-01</com:ProjectCode></com:PwsProjectRef>\n' +
      '                                      <com:PwsProjectRef><com:ProjectCode>220967-02</com:ProjectCode></com:PwsProjectRef>\n' +
      '                                      <com:PwsProjectRef><com:ProjectCode>220967-03</com:ProjectCode></com:PwsProjectRef>\n' +
      '                                      <com:PwsProjectRef><com:ProjectCode>220967-04</com:ProjectCode></com:PwsProjectRef>\n' +
      '                                      <com:PwsProjectRef><com:ProjectCode>220967-05</com:ProjectCode></com:PwsProjectRef>\n' +
      '                                      <com:PwsProjectRef><com:ProjectCode>220967-06</com:ProjectCode></com:PwsProjectRef>\n' +
      '                                      <com:PwsProjectRef><com:ProjectCode>220991</com:ProjectCode></com:PwsProjectRef>\n' +
      '                                      <com:PwsProjectRef><com:ProjectCode>2210125</com:ProjectCode></com:PwsProjectRef>\n' +
      '                                      <com:PwsProjectRef><com:ProjectCode>677800-10593</com:ProjectCode></com:PwsProjectRef>\n' +
      '                                      <com:PwsProjectRef><com:ProjectCode>677900-10594</com:ProjectCode></com:PwsProjectRef>\n' +
      '                                      <com:PwsProjectRef><com:ProjectCode>ARCH - 3707607943</com:ProjectCode></com:PwsProjectRef>\n' +
      '                                      <com:PwsProjectRef><com:ProjectCode>ARCH - 3707682075</com:ProjectCode></com:PwsProjectRef>\n' +
      '                                      <com:PwsProjectRef><com:ProjectCode>ARCH - 3707736194</com:ProjectCode></com:PwsProjectRef>\n' +
      '                                      <com:PwsProjectRef><com:ProjectCode>ARCH - 3707756855</com:ProjectCode></com:PwsProjectRef>\n' +
      '                                      <com:PwsProjectRef><com:ProjectCode>ARCH - 3708308023</com:ProjectCode></com:PwsProjectRef>\n' +
      '                                      <com:PwsProjectRef><com:ProjectCode>ARCH - 3708308024</com:ProjectCode></com:PwsProjectRef>\n' +
      '                                      <com:PwsProjectRef><com:ProjectCode>ARCH - 3708324520</com:ProjectCode></com:PwsProjectRef>\n' +
      '                                      <com:PwsProjectRef><com:ProjectCode>ARCH - 3708387896</com:ProjectCode></com:PwsProjectRef>\n' +
      '                                      <com:PwsProjectRef><com:ProjectCode>ARCH - 3708387898</com:ProjectCode></com:PwsProjectRef>\n' +
      '                                      <com:PwsProjectRef><com:ProjectCode>ARCH - 3708398379</com:ProjectCode></com:PwsProjectRef>\n' +
      '                                      <com:PwsProjectRef><com:ProjectCode>ARCH - 3708437324</com:ProjectCode></com:PwsProjectRef>\n' +
      '                                      <com:PwsProjectRef><com:ProjectCode>ARCH - 3708437327</com:ProjectCode></com:PwsProjectRef>\n' +
      '                                      <com:PwsProjectRef><com:ProjectCode>ARCH - 3708437328</com:ProjectCode></com:PwsProjectRef>\n' +
      '                                      <com:PwsProjectRef><com:ProjectCode>ARCH - 3708478136</com:ProjectCode></com:PwsProjectRef>\n' +
      '                                      <com:PwsProjectRef><com:ProjectCode>ARCH - 3708510538</com:ProjectCode></com:PwsProjectRef>\n' +
      '                                      <com:PwsProjectRef><com:ProjectCode>ARCH - 3708510540</com:ProjectCode></com:PwsProjectRef>\n' +
      '                                      <com:PwsProjectRef><com:ProjectCode>ARCH - 3708567478</com:ProjectCode></com:PwsProjectRef>\n' +
      '                                      <com:PwsProjectRef><com:ProjectCode>ARCH - 3708587301</com:ProjectCode></com:PwsProjectRef>\n' +
      '                                      <com:PwsProjectRef><com:ProjectCode>ARCH - 3708608015</com:ProjectCode></com:PwsProjectRef>\n' +
      '             '... 231 more characters
  },
```

the issue i'm having is that Axios is returning what appears to be hex/binary data *back* from this call:

```
 data: '\x1F�\b\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00��\x07`\x1CI�%&/m�{\x7FJ�J��t�\b�`\x13$ؐ@\x10������\x1DiG#)�*��eVe]f\x16@�흼��{���{���;�N\'���?\\fd\x01l��J�ɞ!���\x1F?~|\x1F?"\x1E7�N��yY���ݢ\\6���>�����ݻ�t�/�fL�7U�\x1AW��]�r7�7�~tD�?�f�G�_^5���˺��|ھʛU�l\x14�\x05��o�z�d�i��K/�\x1BU�:�/�i�\x00(}\x1E\x00[���z�\r\x03{��
�I�l�l�6w
```

when I should be getting XML back. However, in that for loop, if I remove the else statement:

```
  for(let i = 0; i < idArray.length; i++){

        if (i === 0){
          genXML = idArray[i].XMLCode + "\n";
        }
        if (i === idArray.length - 1){
          genXML = genXML + "                                      " + idArray[i].XMLCode;
        }
      }
```

which generates:

```
    data: '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n' +
      '                      <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:com="http://projectorpsa.com/DataContracts/Shared/Common/" \n' +
      '                      xmlns:pws="http://projectorpsa.com/PwsProjectorServices/" xmlns:req="http://projectorpsa.com/DataContracts/Requests/" xmlns:sch="http://projectorpsa.com/DataContracts/Shared/Scheduling/">\n' +
      '                         <soapenv:Header />\n' +
      '                         <soapenv:Body>\n' +
      '                            <pws:PwsGetProject>\n' +
      '                               <pws:serviceRequest>\n' +
      '                                  <req:SessionTicket>B</req:SessionTicket>\n' +
      '                                  <sch:Mode>R</sch:Mode>\n' +
      '                                  <sch:ProjectIdentities>\n' +
      '                                      <com:PwsProjectRef><com:ProjectCode>201268</com:ProjectCode></com:PwsProjectRef>\n' +
      '                                      <com:PwsProjectRef><com:ProjectCode>ARCH - 3708608015</com:ProjectCode></com:PwsProjectRef>\n' +
      '                                  </sch:ProjectIdentities>\n' +
      '                               </pws:serviceRequest>\n' +
      '                            </pws:PwsGetProject>\n' +
      '                         </soapenv:Body>\n' +
      '                      </soapenv:Envelope>\n'
  },
```

it works perfectly, generating the XML I need back. So I'm presuming my issue is with how that else statement is being formulated. Even though it all appears to look good and well. I'm at a loss as to why axios is doing this. In the above post I mentioned that other libraries are working fine with this, but I can't get Axios to do it. Hoping someone might have a idea!

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this [SOAP calculator service](http://www.dneonline.com/calculator.asmx?wsdl)?

I test with `curl` and `axios`
Axios post program not return with `\n`.

It can decide your `SOAP server issue` or `axios program` issue.

curl demo

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://www.dneonline.com/calculator.asmx' \
--header 'Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8' \
--header 'SOAPAction: http://tempuri.org/Add' \
--data-raw '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <Add xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <intA>100</intA>
      <intB>100</intB>
    </Add>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
'
```

response

```
$ curl --location --request POST 'http://www.dneonline.com/calculator.asmx' \
> --header 'Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8' \
> --header 'SOAPAction: http://tempuri.org/Add' \
> --data-raw '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
>   <soap:Body>
>     <Add xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
>       <intA>100</intA>
>       <intB>100</intB>
>     </Add>
>   </soap:Body>
> </soap:Envelope>
> '
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><AddResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"><AddResult>200</AddResult></AddResponse></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

axios code

```
const axios = require("axios");

const getAdd = async () => {
    try {
        const response = await axios.post(
            'http://www.dneonline.com/calculator.asmx',
            '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>\n<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">\n  <soap:Body>\n    <Add xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">\n      <intA>100</intA>\n      <intB>100</intB>\n    </Add>\n  </soap:Body>\n</soap:Envelope>\n',
            {
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'text/xml; charset=utf-8',
                    'SOAPAction': 'http://tempuri.org/Add'
                }
            }
        );
        console.log(response.data);
    } catch (err) {
        // Handle Error Here
        console.error(err);
    }
};

getAdd();
```

response

```
$ node add.js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><AddResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"><AddResult>200</AddResult></AddResponse></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

Both no return `\n` in XML returned data.

If you test with my axios code(add calculator) with no '\n' value.

It means not a axios issue, it may be your SOAP server issue.